# TFS 2015 - TF401002: The SQL Server Database Engine failed to save the database backup to path

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015

When attempting to create scheduled backups for TFS 2015, I received the following message: "TF401002: The SQL Server Database Engine failed to save the database backup to path \{share}\d$\TFSBackups.  Please grant SQL service account read/write access to that folder."

I can't seem to find a solution that will work for me.  The 'TFSBackups' folder is shared with full permissions for the NETWORK SERVICE and MSSQLSERVER.

What haven't I done?

Comment: The error message is crystal clear and has nothing to do with TFS. That account doesn't have permission to write to that folder. The path is **NOT** a path to a valid share, it uses the administrative endpoint `d$` to directly access a physical drive. Only administrators are allowed to use administrative endpoints. Just share `TFSBackups`, set the proper permissions and use the share's path, eg `\\MyStorageMachine\TFSBackups`

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.

Comment: You could add the solution in the answer and mark it, which will also help others in community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the comment from  *Panagiotis Kanavos* in the answer.

> The error message is crystal clear and has nothing to do with TFS.
>   **That account doesn't have permission to write to that folder.**
>
> The path is NOT a path to a valid share, it uses the administrative
>   endpoint d$ to directly access a physical drive. Only administrators
>   are allowed to use administrative endpoints.
>
> Just share TFSBackups, set the proper permissions and use the share's
>   path, eg `\\MyStorageMachine\TFSBackups`

Answer (score 0):

Normally SQL Service is running at user NT Authority/SQLAgent or similar(these users doesn't have authorization to tfs network folder). Go services and change owner of service to an account which has access to tfs folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with TFS, You must be setting up TFS Backups using TFS Admin console.
It is actually the SQL service which write and read backup files to the said location. 
Just make sure you grant access to the SQL Service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Domain pay attention to Domain User Name.

In my case, SQL Server engine was executed by domain user **User@Domain.com** but my true permission was for **Domain\User** so fixing user Logon as in SQL engine saved my day.

Most of the time **NT Authority** doesn't have write permission on network path so, you need to change **Azure** or **TFS** owner user to valid network user.