# Error configuring backup of team foundation server to samba shared path on debian 10 server

Tags: sql-server, tfs, samba

I have a samba 4 configured in debian 10(without joining domain) with my smb.conf configuration file:

```
[global]
        bind interfaces only = yes
        interfaces = 10.0.2.0/24
        workgroup = SAMBA
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        cups options = raw
        encrypt passwords = yes
        logging = file
        smb encrypt = required
        keep alive = 50
        log file = /root/samba/%m.log
        max log size = 100000
        security = user
        map to guest = Bad User

[server]
        path = /server
        writeable = yes
        read only = no
        browsable = yes
        directory mask = 0770
        create mask = 0770
        valid users = juan
```

In tfs (windows server 2012) I configure the backup with the proposed path until I get the following error:

```
error:TF401002: The SQL Server Database Engine was unable to save the database backup in path \\ .... Give the SQL service account read and write access to that folder
```

I go to the database server and the account that does not have permissions to access is the following:

NT Service\SQLAgent$SQLTEAM2013

[image]

as ago to give permissions to that account for the samba shared folder ????

Comment: Post the error in English; Stack Overflow is an English Website. As you've posted an image of the error, we can't even google translate it (which we're advised not to do anyway) meaning your language we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error:TF401002: The SQL Server Database Engine was unable to save the database backup in path \ .... Give the SQL service account read and write access to that folder

It seems that the sql account  doesn't  have sufficient permission.

As far as I know , the `NT Service\SQLAgent$xxx` account is a [virtual account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15#VA_Desc). This account has low user rights.

Generally， this account has no read and write permission for the shared path folder.

You could try to grant permission to this account and check if it could solve this issue.

In addition, you also need to make sure the target path is valid. For example: `\\TFS2018\backup`.

[image: valid path]

[This ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002960/13464420) may be helpful.

Hope this helps.